# reimporting maven project to Eclipse without m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, m2e

I have modular maven project which I firstly imported to eclipse as regular maven project (import => maven => existing maven project). This does not work correctly for our project (many errors etc.).

So I decided to remove this project from eclipse and import it again but as general project (use mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate eclipse project files and then import => general => existing projects into workspace).

But, even when I imported it as general project, Eclipse still import it as maven project (small M icon next to project name in package explorer). What I tried before importing (without success):

- remove .settings directory from each maven module
- remove .project file from each maven module

Do you know how to solve this problem? How can I import maven project as general project when it was before imported as maven project?

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` has not worked properly for several years and it has been retired. It certainly never worked as well as m2e. You're better off working out why m2e is unhappy with your project and resolving that problem.

Comment: To be specific it's one of Opendaylight project. I used mvn eclipse:eclipse many times for those projects and it worked. This time I wanted to try out m2e and it has problems. Even official [Opendaylight project wiki](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:_Eclipse#Help_-_I_still_have_Red_X.27s.21_.28i.e._Eclipse_compile_errors.29) states, that m2e is not fully supported without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found is to disable Maven nature of project.

Projects which was imported as Maven project can be "converted" back to "general" project by `project context menu => Maven => Disable Maven Nature`